# Digital Ink Pad tablet doens't work in 20.04, but does in 16.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics-tablet, usbhid

I'm upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04. I have a graphics-tablet connected with my computer that 16.04 recognizes pen as a mouse. But it doesn't work in 20.04. Output from *usb-devices* are identical for both versions:

```
T:  Bus=04 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=172f ProdID=0027 Rev=01.50
S:  Manufacturer=               
S:  Product=Digital Ink Pad
S:  SerialNumber=01.00.00
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

But the results of *xinput list-props* is very different. In 16.04 gives

```
Device '                Digital Ink Pad':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (281): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (282):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (283):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (284):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (272):    5935, 39
    Device Node (273):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (285): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (286):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (287):  0
    Axis Labels (288):  "Abs X" (278), "Abs Y" (279), "Abs Pressure" (280), "Rel Vert Wheel" (277)
    Button Labels (289):    "Button Left" (156), "Button Middle" (157), "Button Right" (158), "Button Wheel Up" (159), "Button Wheel Down" (160), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (161), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (162)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (290): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (291):    1
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (292):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (293): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (294): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (295):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (296):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (297):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (298):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (299):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (300):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (301): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (302):  0
```

But in 20.04 gives

```
Device '                Digital Ink Pad Mouse':
    Device Enabled (155):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (291):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (292):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (293):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (294):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (295):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (296): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (297): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (298):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (299):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (300): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (301): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (302):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (303):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (304):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (305): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (306): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (276): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (277):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (278):    0, 0
    Device Node (279):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Device Product ID (280):    5935, 39
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (307):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (308):   1
```

Comment: You mention upgrading from 16.04 LTS, which had two upgrade paths; 16.10 or to next LTS being 18.04 LTS.  Are you talking a re-install? or something else as you've mentioned something outside tested upgrade paths.

Comment: It's not a distro upgrade. I put another HD and install 20.04.
BTW, 16.04 is standard Ubuntu + mate desktop.  20.04 is Ubuntu mate

Answer (score 4):

Based on the `xinput` output you've provided, it looks like the driver changed from `evdev` to `libinput`.

- You can try forcing `libinput` to treat the device as a tablet by adding the following to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

  ```
  Section "InputClass"
      Identifier "evdev tablet"
      MatchIsTablet "on"
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event3"
      Driver "evdev"
  EndSection
  ```
- You can try reverting to `evdev`.

  1. Make sure the package `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` is installed. (This may or may not be sufficient.)

     ```
     sudo apt list xserver-xorg-input-evdev
     sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
     ```
  2. You may need to disable `libinput`. You may need to add the `Ignore` option to multiple sections in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`:

     ```
     Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
         MatchIsPointer "on"
         MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
         Driver "libinput"
         Option "Ignore" "on"
     EndSection
     ```
  3. You *may* need to add the following to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`:

     ```
     Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "evdev tablet"
         MatchIsTablet "on"
         MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event3"
         Driver "evdev"
     EndSection
     ```

Comment: Thanks! xiota, you gave me the key. But I used another aproach to switch from libinput to evdev. I make a copy of 10-evdev.conf with name 80-tablet.conf, so it overides all assignements to libinput